# Simple homebrew formula for Python

Tags: homebrew

I have a simple python app that I want to distribute via a private Homebrew tap. I have the following files in the main repo:

```
test/
  test.sh     # script that runs the python script below.
  main.py     # main script.
```

And the following config (test.rb) committed to my tap repo:

```
class Test < Formula
  desc "Test."
  url "https://github.com/..."
  version "0.0.1"

  def install
    bin.install "test.sh"
  end

  test do
  end
end
```

But when I install the main.py file is not available.

1. How do I distribute (and reference) the related source scripts?
2. Can I rename the symlink that is created in /usr/local/bin?
3. Are there more complete docs than: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md (e.g., listing the complete command syntax?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above formula doesn't mention the python file, so it's not installed. You could try something like:

```
libexec.install "test.sh", "main.py"
bin.install_symlink libexec/"test.sh" => "test"
```

Here are the full docs: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tree/master/share/doc/homebrew

Comment: Thanks very much -- that worked. It was tricky figuring out the path to the script from the symlink though. I got it working but it seems like I'm missing something? 

DIR=$(cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd)
SCRIPT=$(dirname $(readlink "$0"))
ROOT=$DIR/$SCRIPT/../libexec
python $ROOT/main.py $@